# Locking stand alone ArcGIS Tool?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-script-tool

I have written a number of standalone Tools for ArcMap.

These tools are all .py files and are run outside of ArcMap. At the moment it has only been me running these tools, but I have been asked to share these with other users.

I am happy to share these, I am however not entirely happy in sharing the lessons and tricks of the trade I have incorporated into the flow of these tools.

Can I lock these files from viewing by people who shouldn’t see the text within the .py file, but still keep the script accessible to the windows task manager or a single run “double-click”?

As an aside, I would prefer to not embed these in a Toolbox, as I want to run these outside of ArcMap /ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: If you don't want to embed/password protect the TBX, nor create a PYT in Pro and [Encrypt it](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/encryptpyt.htm), and your question is about "Securing" basic `.py` files, I'd say you'd want to use stackoverflow to research your question as its no longer about GIS and just about securing python files.

Comment: Thank you @KHibma I thought I would try here first. Perhaps I should look at keeping them in a Toolbox as it’s easier to protect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to protect your scripts and run them from another script outside the ArcMap environment.

You need to create a toolbox and wire up your scripts as tools as if you were going to run them from tool box. You then import the script into the toolbox and protect with a password, this is documented as [Embedding scripts and password protecting tools](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/sharing-workflows/embedding-scripts-and-password-protecting-tools.htm).

So for example create a toolbox called protected.tbx, set its alias to something, I used testtbx. Create a script tool, import and protect with password. Make a record of the script NAME not the LABEL.

So in my test I have a script tool called scrCount which takes as input a FeatureClass and does a count on the rows.

Now create your outside Arcmap script, the trick here is to import your script from your password protected toolbox so you could call it.

```py
import arcpy
def main():
    fc = r"C:\Scratch\fGDB_Scratch.gdb\BankSide_Buffer"
    toolboxpath = r"C:\Scratch\protected.tbx"
    arcpy.ImportToolbox(toolboxpath,"testtbx")
    arcpy.scrCount_testtbx(fc) # Name_toolbox alias

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I can only assume if you are reporting messages then you will need to use the print statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to convert them to executables with PyInstaller (http://www.pyinstaller.org/). But then you are not able to run them from ArcMap anymore.

There may be some issues regarding ArcPy and PyInstaller. I think you will find some workarounds here: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/576

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this. I tried PyInstaller once, it didn’t work as I intended. But I’ll definitely give it a go.